# Hash tag links in #each loop with Handlebars and Ember

Tags: html, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an array of objects:

```
objects = [
    {
        name: "a",
        val: 1
    }, 
    {
        name: "b", 
        val: 2
    }
]
```

I'm trying to produce the following HTML with Handlebars:

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href="#a">...</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#b">...</a> </li>
</ul>
```

If I didn't need the hash, I would do it like this:

```
<ul>
    {{#objects}}
        <li> <a {{bindAttr href="name"}}>...</a> </li>
    {{/objects}}
</ul>
```

I can't use `href="#name"` or `href=#"name"`. Is there a way to get the hash in front of the name property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
    {{#each item in objects}}
        <li> <a href="#{{unbound item.name}}">...</a> </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

But i'm not sure what you're doing, you probably want to use the link-to helper

Comment: I'm actually creating some Bootstrap elements with click-to-toggle type stuff for every item and was having trouble setting the targets correctly. Your solution works great, thanks!